# Ender 3 BLTouch not working with BigTreeTech SKR mini e3 or stock motherboard

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, bltouch, bigtreetech

When my Ender 3 was on the stock motherboard, I went through two BLTouch sensors.  In both cases, we had the same result: sometimes, when homing with the sensor, the printer would jam the gantry down into the bed because it would miss the sensor.  When leveling, it would intermittently stop before it had completed all the steps.

Alas, since I have a glass bed I cannot use the Z-axis limit switch for homing (without mechanical modification, anyways.)

I installed a BigTreeTech SKR mini e3 motherboard.  Motion control works fine.  In fact, it's much, much quieter.  Sadly, still have lousy results (although I've only tried one sensor on this one.)

- Z Limit switch plugged in: The BLTouch Deploys.  The board totally ignores the sensor (even when I shove it home with my fingers on the way down) and drives into the board.
- Z Limit switch not plugged in: The BLTouch seems to deploy and stow over and over again.  Then, the printer just says "STOPPED".

Does anyone have any suggestions?

(I think I've been using the same wire this whole time, for what that's worth.)

Comment: Is it a genuine BLTouch or a Creality clone? Did you configure the sensor correctly in firmware and using the correct pins on the board? Maybe show a photo how you connected the sensor and how you configured it in the firmware config files.

Comment: I just ordered one on amazon that claims to be from BigTreeTech. The one I have now is just a ribbon connector, so I feel as if you can't mess it up.... But I'll some pictures when I can!

Comment: If it is from BTT it is a clone, my experience with clones led me to conclude to never buy these ever again. I can imagine you think you can't do wrong with a ribbon cable, but you do need to have that configured in your firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue and fixed it by removing the z-stop cable and using the black and white (the combined 2 wires on the BLTouch). Below is a diagram that may help.

[image: BLTouch wiring to z end stop]

Comment: I wound up doing the same thing.  Thanks.